# Use table summary on specific values in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello I have a df such as :

```
query    G1 G2 G3 G4 G5
SP1      A  B  NA NA B
SP2      B  F  NA G  NA
SP3      NA NA NA C  B
SP4      NA NA NA C  C
```

and I would like to count for each `SPN` the number of cell with `A` and `B`

for instance for `SP1` there are `3`
for `SP2 : 1`
etc at the and I should get ;

```
    nb
SP1 3
SP2 1
SP3 1
SP4 0
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work, using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% rownames_to_column('SP') %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(),~ replace_na(.,'0'))) %>% 
   unite(new,-SP,sep='') %>% mutate(nb= str_count(new,'A|B')) %>% 
   column_to_rownames('SP') %>% select(2)
    nb
SP1  3
SP2  1
SP3  1
SP4  0
```

Comment: Hello, what if the column with sp names is ```query``` ? I tried to replace 'SP' by query but it does not work

Comment: So, I did that rownames_to_column because dplyr doesn't carry rownames, so we created a column from row names and finally, we are returing that column as rownames.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this,

```
df<-data.frame(G1=c("A","B", NA, NA), G2=c("B","F",NA,NA),G3=c(NA,NA,NA,NA),G4=c(NA,"G","C","C"),G5=c("B",NA,"B","C"))
rownames(df)<-c("SP1","SP2","SP3","SP4")
data.frame(nb=apply(df, 1,function(x) sum(x %in% c("A","B") )))
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness I'm adding this as an answer:

```r
> rowSums(matrix(as.matrix(df)  %in% c("A","B"), nrow=nrow(df), dimnames= list(df$query,NULL)))
#> SP1 SP2 SP3 SP4 
#>   3   1   1   0
```